# How to resolve Cannot load such file openssl error?

Tags: ruby, openssl

I tried running gem install bundler and got this error, have tried all the link on SO already, please help.

```
Ignoring eventmachine-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine eventmachine --version 1.2.7
Ignoring nokogiri-1.10.10 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.10.10
Ignoring oj-3.7.12 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine oj --version 3.7.12
Ignoring yaji-0.3.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine yaji --version 0.3.6
Ignoring yaji-0.3.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine yaji --version 0.3.5
ERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    cannot load such file -- openssl
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Uninstall ruby and opensssl and then run this:

```
rvm reinstall 2.2.9 --with-openssl-dir=$HOME/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: I have `rvm 1.29.12` on macOS and there is no such directory as `~/.rvm/usr`. However, I have `~/.rvm/user`. Is it the same?